# URL Rewriting (PHP & Apache Local Server)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using EasyPHP 14.1 DevServer and I'm currently developping my own website on my computer.
I was introduced to a new method called URL Routing/Rewriting today.
I found [this](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php) useful website that generates the lines that I need to add to my httpd.conf file.

(I've double checked and the rewrite module is running)

I tried a quick example, a few ones actually, and none of them worked.

I tried to redirect myself from http://localhost/47.html to http://localhost/site1/showproducts.php?id=47 by adding these lines to httpd.conf

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /site1/showproducts.php?id=$1 [L]
```

I wanted this link http://localhost/site1/products/47/ to lead to http://localhost/site1/showproduct.php?id=47

I'm fairly new to this, so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Where do you place that rule, inside the host configuration or in `.htaccess` style files? The syntax differs between the two options (where the first should be preferred)...

Comment: Do you want to rewrite *"/site1/products/47/"* to *"/site1/showproduct.php?id=47"* ?

Comment: I placed it in the httpd.conf file, aka the host config.
And yes 5ervant, I want to do that

Comment: @ExuberantArtichoke: this is the demo, http://softbazz.net63.net/my/12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok just update that,

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule    ^products/([0-9]+)/?$    showproduct.php?id=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
```

This will work.

Comment: Thaanks a lot, it worked :D
Although, I was wondering, how to add some sort of an understand-able text to the link, like the one stackoverflow for example
stackoverflow.com/questions/31086984/ **url-rewriting-php-apache-local-server**